# How can I tell what recovery model my DB is using?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a SQL command I can run to get the recovery model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('YourDatabaseName', 'RECOVERY')
```

OR

```
SELECT d.recovery_model_desc 
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.name = 'YourDatabaseName'
```

Answer (score 0):

since we have servers with overlapping lists of db's, I run (in master)

'select ,d.name,d.recovery_model_desc from sys.databases d'